# find sequences from rows of data

Tags: r

I'm working with a dataframe containing a series of "events" and the dates on which they occurred. These events are sequential, where one follows another, but there are multiple separate sequences.

The data is structured so that each row shows an event (`event_name`) and an event that followed it at some point later on in the sequence (`later_event_name`). See below:

```
   event_name  event_date later_event_name later_event_date
1           A  2020-01-01                B       2020-02-01
2           A  2020-01-01                C       2020-03-01
3           A  2020-01-01                G       2020-07-01
4           B  2020-02-01                C       2020-03-01
5           B  2020-02-01                G       2020-07-01
6           C  2020-03-01                G       2020-07-01
7           D  2020-04-01                F       2020-06-01
8           D  2020-04-01                I       2020-09-01
9           F  2020-06-01                I       2020-09-01
10          E  2020-05-01                H       2020-08-01
```

In this case, `F` and `I` both follow `D`, and `I` follows `F`, so the sequence is `D`->`F`->`I`.

There are three sequences in this dataframe:

1. `A`->`B`->`C`->`G`
2. `D`->`F`->`I`
3. `E`->`H`

My actual data comprises thousands of rows. I'd like to be able to automate the process of grouping the events that comprise each sequence. An idea final output would be as follows:

```
# the desired output
# `seq_id` is the identifier for each separate sequence
# `seq` shows the order of each event within that sequence
  seq_id seq event_name event_date
1      1   1          A 2020-01-01
2      1   2          B 2020-02-01
3      1   3          C 2020-03-01
4      1   4          G 2020-07-01
5      2   1          D 2020-04-01
6      2   2          F 2020-06-01
7      2   3          I 2020-09-01
8      3   1          E 2020-05-01
9      3   2          H 2020-08-01
```

Here is the dummy data:

```
# the input data
structure(list(event_name = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "D", "D", "F", "E"),
               event_date = structure(c(18262, 18262, 18262, 
                                        18293, 18293, 18322, 18353, 18353, 18414, 18383), class = "Date"),
               later_event_name = c("B", "C", "G", "C", "G", "G", "F", "I", "I", "H"),
               later_event_date = structure(c(18293, 18322, 18444, 
                                              18322, 18444, 18444, 18414, 18506, 18506, 18475), class = "Date")),
          row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Some notes:

- sequences can be any length from two upwards.
- For simplicity I've here named the events "A", "B", and so on, but in reality their IDs are alphanumeric codes with no logical pattern or sequence.

Comment: What if the event chain bifurcates? For example, A-->B and A-->C, but B and C happen on the same date.

Comment: @ekoam great question! Fortunately these events have unique dates (they cannot occur on the same day), so this issue won't arise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to conceptualize this as a network graph.  If the data is ordered by `event_date` and `later_event_date` then the order of the cluster membership will reflect this.

```
# Order data frame by dates if needed
# df <- df[order(df$event_date, df$later_event_date), ]

library(igraph)

# Create network graph
g <- graph_from_data_frame(df[grep("name$", names(df))], directed = TRUE)
```

You can see the membership of the clusters by:

```
split(names(V(g)), components(g)$membership)

$`1`
[1] "A" "B" "C" "G"

$`2`
[1] "D" "F" "I"

$`3`
[1] "E" "H"
```

Create data frame of cluster membership:

```
res <- data.frame(event = names(components(g)$membership), ind = components(g)$membership)

# Assign within cluster id
res$seq_n <- with(res, ave(event, ind, FUN = seq_along))

# Merge with dates by events
res <- merge(unique(rbind(df[1:2], setNames(df[3:4], names(df[1:2])))), res, by.y = "event", by.x = "event_name", all.y = TRUE)

# Order by index if needed
res[order(res$ind), ]

  event_name event_date ind seq_n
1          A 2020-01-01   1     1
2          B 2020-02-01   1     2
3          C 2020-03-01   1     3
7          G 2020-07-01   1     4
4          D 2020-04-01   2     1
6          F 2020-06-01   2     2
9          I 2020-09-01   2     3
5          E 2020-05-01   3     1
8          H 2020-08-01   3     2
```

Comment: thank you @27 ϕ 9 for a very creative solution

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that achieves the result through reshaping the data (making use of `dplyr` and `tidyr`). Not exactly elegant, but it seems to work!

```
# requires that the columns are first renamed as follows
df <- rename(df, event1_name = event_name, event1_date = event_date, event2_name = later_event_name, event2_date = later_event_date)

df %>%
  # only need the 'root' of each sequence
  filter(!(event1_name %in% event2_name)) %>%

  # add an identifier for each sequence
  mutate(seq_id = as.numeric(factor(event1_name))) %>%

  # draw event data into a single set of columns
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("event"), 
               names_to = c("event_pos", ".value"),
               names_pattern = "^event(.)_(.*)$") %>%

  # remove the duplicate rows (the roots of each sequence)
  distinct() %>%

  # add the indices of each sequence
  select(-event_pos) %>%
  group_by(seq_id) %>%
  arrange(date, .by_group = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(seq = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup()
```